# How many pairs of cells spreadsheet are non-empty?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have cells in columns A and B. I am interested in the cases in which neither the cell in column A nor its neighbour in column B is empty. (For example, when cells A12 and B12 both contain something.)

How can I count the number of times both cells in a pair are non-empty?

So far, I've had a column C, with each cell having `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A2),ISBLANK(B2)), 0, 1)`, `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A3),ISBLANK(B3)), 0, 1)`, etc. with a `SUM` function at the bottom of Column C, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to count these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COUNTIFS should do this handily.

```
=countifs(a:a, "<>", b:b, "<>")
```

Comment: Much more efficient than what I was doing!

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY(A:B, "select A where A is not null and B is not null")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Wow, API Query Language is very powerful! Thanks for showing me this, but I think I'll use the `Countifs` function @user11217663 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"",B:B<>"")))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

## SUMPRODUCT 'Deals' in Arrays 4

Calculates (counts) the number of rows where cells in column `A` **AND** column `B`, contain data.

> ```
> =SUMPRODUCT(--NOT(ISBLANK(A$1:A$5000)),--NOT(ISBLANK(B$1:B$5000)))
> ```

Calculates (counts) the number of rows where cells in column `A` **AND** column `B`, are blank.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISBLANK(A$1:A$5000),--ISBLANK(B$1:B$5000))
```

Would appreciate anyone's feedback if the following formula is working and in which Excel version (not working in 2003):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)),--NOT(ISBLANK(B:B)))
```